# vue.js: v-for doesn't rerender content when array changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why v-for doesn't react to change some element in array?

```
this.test[3] = 3
```

If later I will call push for array, only then Vue rerender content.

```
this.test[3] = 3;
this.push(4);
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/debJqK

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    test: [1, 2],
  },
  methods: {
    changeVar1: function() {
      this.test[3] = 3;
      this.test.push(4);
    },
    changeVar2: function() {
      this.test[3] = 3;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  padding: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeVar1()">Work</button>
  <button @click="changeVar2()">Doesn't work</button>
  <p v-for="(index, digit) in test">{{digit}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to redirect you also to [this](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating) where it explains the reactivity of the DOM regarding either object or array changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add elements by index, you [have to call `Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

```
Vue.set(this.test, 3, 3);
```

Or:

```
this.test.splice(3, 1, 3)
```

This enables Vue to adjust the reactivity to that element. [**Updated codePen**](https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/BxBYqQ).

## Why?

Besides regular caveat problems, the docs have [a specific guidance on arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats):

> #### Caveats
>
> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue **cannot** detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> var vm = new Vue({
>   data: {
>     items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
>   }
> })
> vm.items[1] = 'x' // is NOT reactive
> vm.items.length = 2 // is NOT reactive
> ```
>
> To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same
> as `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, but will also trigger state
> updates in the reactivity system:
>
> ```
> // Vue.set
> Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
>
> // Array.prototype.splice
> vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
> ```
>
> You can also use the [`vm.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)
> instance method, which is an alias for the global `Vue.set`:
>
> ```
> vm.$set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
> ```
>
> To deal with caveat 2, you can use `splice`:
>
> ```
> vm.items.splice(newLength)
> ```

Updated stack snippet:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    test: [1, 2],
  },
  methods: {
    changeVar1: function() {
      this.test[3] = 3;
      this.test.push(4);
    },
    changeVar2: function() {
      Vue.set(this.test, 3, 3);
      // this.test.splice(3, 1, 3); // would work the same
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  padding: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeVar1()">Work</button>
  <button @click="changeVar2()">Didn't work, now fixed</button>
  <p v-for="(index, digit) in test">{{digit}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted! But  can you extend on this? "Why" is more important that "How"

Comment: @samayo read the link `Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method:`